# Is there a free or cheap and reliable ISO burning software for Windows?

Tags: iso-image, dvd-burning, cd-burning

I'd like to burn CD iso files and DVD iso files on Windows using my DVD burner.  What software is the cheapest (retail, not using bit torrents) or free and doesn't contain adware or malware?

EDIT:

@DrZoo - When uploading to Google Drive, and then download the file you just uploaded.  It says ImgBurn has a virus.

[image]

Comment: I use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/)

Comment: @DrZoo - Can you give me the exact steps you used to download it?  Did your computer get infected?

Comment: Nope, no problems at all. It's a rather popular free ISO burning software. I downloaded it from their [website](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download&) and used one of the mirrors, but you can also download it from [Ninite](https://ninite.com/) or something.

Comment: @DrZoo - See my edit above.  Might want to try that workflow in Google Drive with the one in your Downloads folder, and make sure you don't have a virus.

Comment: You don't have a virus; [the original file is infected](https://virustotal.com/en/file/ab5ab68b541c0de51d7e9eafe1cbe5267347c1e6edf1faeedc79e01fd774375e/analysis/). So, if you _ran_ it, then you're screwed...

Comment: @Michael Hampton - what software do you use to check for infected files?

Comment: Um, did you click the link? In this particular case you can see that it has the [OpenCandy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCandy) malware.

Comment: @Michael- yah I saw your link.  Thought maybe there was a good Windows app for these files.

Comment: Those detections appear to be for Opencandy--adware, not a virus.  And when I download straight from their site I get the same thing.

Comment: Going through the install process, I think it's because it asks if you want to install Baidu Advanced ScreenSnapshot which would be considered adware or something. You can obviously uncheck the box and it won't install Baidu. I've used the program for years and I've never had any problem.

Comment: http://infrarecorder.org/

Comment: In [forum post about OpenCandy and ImgBurn](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?/topic/21658-opencandy-adware-was-a-bad-decision-and-will-cost-you-your-good-reputation/), software author LightningUK! stands by his decision to use it.  Do not install OpenCandy.  Apparently ImgBurn's installer gives you an option to NOT install OpenCandy.  The ImgBurn program ain't bad, once you get it installed without OpenCandy.  Your anti-virus software is likely complaining about ImgBurn's installer because of OpenCandy.  Can you disable your Anti-Virus?  If no, try extracting with 7-zip, or try infrarecorder

Comment: Voting to close; question's description does not match title.  Title is likely to provoke numerous answers, as it is opinionated.  (Maybe a better fit for [http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)?  Question already has some useful info (answers/comments).  If original poster wants more details, then adjusting question (or making a new/different question) is recommended.  As is, the current state of this question is not a very good fit for SuperUser.

Comment: I have used ImgBurn for years, it isn't a virus, but I would agree this question is not on topic and never was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has a built-in image burner. Just right-click on the .iso file and open it with Windows Disc Image Burner if it isn't the default action already.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/burn-a-cd-or-dvd-from-an-iso-file

Comment: Clarifying the answer: right click *.iso file > Open With > Windows Disc Image Burner

Comment: True as of WIn7.  Maybe Vista.  I don't think XP had the ISOBURN.EXE program.

Answer (score 0):

BurnAware is a  full-featured and free burning software to create CD, DVD discs of all types.
operating system support:Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/Server 2008/7/8/10
latest version released: BurnAware v9.1